# How to remove configurable products from category list ONLY

Tags: php, magento, catalog

I need to show only simple products in category page, but I cant set "not visible" to the configurable because I need the an active product page from the configurables.

I found this code to remove the configurables from the listing:

```
  $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
  $_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
  $_productCollection->clear()
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')
                     ->load();

  $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

It works, but, In the layered navigation the configurable product are still counting. Its like "Color: Red (2)" but I just have 1 red (simple).
How can I remove completly the configurable products?

Comment: Why are those products in the category to begin with if you don't want them there?

Comment: Because when the user are in the product page (configurable), i need the full breadcrumb (Home > category > subcateogry > product)
Im using a color swatch module. I want to display all simple products in the category page, and when the user clicks in some product, he goes to the configurable product of that simple product, with the full breadcrumb

Answer (score 2):

The layered navigation uses a collection object which is loaded separately.

One possible way to ensure correct counts next to the navigation filters is to override model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer` and add your filter to its function `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection`

```
public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite($this->getCurrentCategory()->getId())
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple');

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

        return $this;
    }
```

To achieve this create a module in your **local** code pool. In the `config.xml` file  add the following node into  the `global` node

```
<models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer>YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Rewrite_Layer</layer>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
</models>
```

In your module add a directory 'Rewrite' under folder 'Model' and create a file `Layer.php` in it. In the created file `Model/Rewrite/Layer.php` add a class with the following definition:

```
class YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Rewrite_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer {
}
```

Add the function above into this class, clear cache.

Comment: Thank you! But can you be more specific about how can I do that? Witch core file I need to copy to 'local' ?

Comment: Don't copy any core file into local, use a model rewrite as preferred in Magento. See my answer update

Comment: Ok, got it. I created the module and Magento are loading the rewrite. It solved part of the problem, because before that, the infinite-ajax-loading that im using was trying to load the configurables too, and now its not. But, the layered navigation is still counting the configurables (im using magento 1.7.2)